# How to add attribute to tr using JSON and Footable v3?

Tags: json, footable

I'm using Footable 3.0.9 and loading in data using JSON. 
Example:
http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/component/showcase.html

I would like to add an html attribute to each `<tr>`, in this case `'data-id'`, so I can then use js on the row. The id is set in the JSON, but I'm not sure how to then set that as the `data-id` attribute on its tr

Comment: Would you share some code of your table creation ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with footable but with jQuery you can set data attribute easily.

```
var a = $('#mydiv').data('id'); //getter

$('#mydiv').data('id', 'mydiv_1'); //setter
```

So in footable code:

```
$editor.find('#id').val(values.id);
$editor.find('#id').data('id', values.id);
```